# How to custom popup style?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I would like to create a new style for recenter the map in popup.
I don't see how do..

Example :

[image]

Comment: look your question, I guess you forgot something

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in same way as you would center any div inside another.